# Jmeter-JDBC request wait till have result

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to run the performance script which has API which takes the payload as file from S3 and submit to target system. After the request is completed I need to login to db and verify the status of the transaction. Here there is delay in getting inserted to db which is fast for payload with small file size. As I started submitting large files 1 GB to 15 GB, there will be delay in inserting a table.

So the JDBC request which has modified_date will be null for large payload. I have used constant timer but not sure how long it takes to insert in table.
Is there any way I can make jdbc request to wait till i get result for modified_date for message table.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your JDBC Request sampler under the [While Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller) and use i.e. following [jexl3() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) as the condition:

```
${__jexl3("${modified_date}" == "null",)}
```

[image]

Once done you can use the Constant Timer for introducing the reasonable delay, i.e. run the JDBC Request each second or several seconds until the result is there.

More information: [Using the While Controller in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter)

Comment: While controller is not exiting once there is value for modified_date